# Understanding simulation in the secretary problem

Tags: self-study, simulation, secretary-problem

I'm working on the following problem:

> When applying for a secretarial position, $n$ candidates line up in random order for interviews, where the manager after each interview has to decide to take or decline that candidate. His assessment is qualitative in the sense that at interview $k\geq 2$, he observes only $Y_{k,n}$, the indicator that candidate $k$ is better than candidates $1,\ldots,k−1,$ and his goal is to find a strategy whose probability of selecting the best candidate is close to the maximal value $p_n^*$. It is easy to see that the optimal strategy is to select candidate $$\tau_{k,n}\stackrel{def}{=}\inf\{l\geq k: Y_{l,n}\} = 1\}\land n $$ for some $k\in\{2,\ldots,n\}$. Let $k_n^*$ denote the optimal such $k$. Plot simulation estimates of $k_n^*$ and $p_n^*$ for $n = 5,\ldots, 50,$ and compare with the known asymptotics $k_n^*\sim n/e, p_n^*\sim 1/e$.

**Question:** Why would you choose to simulate $k_n^*$? And if you decided to do so; how? The fact that you could simulate $k_n^*$ indicates that $k_n^*$ has some kind of distribution. I don't get why since $k_n^*$ seems (I'm apparently mistaken) like a deterministic value to me.

The secretary problem is described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secretary_problem). For an arbitrary $k$, the probability that the best applicant is selected is equal to $$P(k) = \sum_{i = 1}^n P(\text{applicant $i$ is selected$\cap$applicant $i$ is the best})$$ If we fast forward through some derivations we find that $$P(k) = \sum_{i=r}^n\dfrac{r-1}{i -1}\times \dfrac{1}{n} = \dfrac{r-1}{n}\sum_{i = r}^n\dfrac{1}{i-1}$$ This means that $k_n^*$ can be found by just checking for which $k$ the value $P(k)$ is maximal.

**Edit:** The only thing I can think of right now is that you might want to simulate per case which $k$ would give you the optimal candidate. But then again, we would know which $k$ that would be; if the optimal candidate were on the $m$-th place, we would want to skip the first $m-1$ candidates, so I don't see what simulation would bring to the table.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Why Simulate?

Quick research into the problem will reveal that the optimal algorithm to solve this problem is to rank the first $\frac{1}{e}$ applicants, not hire them, and then choose the first candidate who is better than your previous ones. For example, if there are ten candidates each with unique rankings, you might observe the following sequence.

$$2 \quad 3 \quad 6 \quad 5 \quad 4 \quad 8 \quad 9 \quad 10 \quad 1 \quad 7$$

We observe that in the first $\lfloor \frac{1}{e} \rfloor$ candidates, or first 3 candidates, the max score was a six. So, we check the fourth candidate and observe a 5, so we don't hire. Then we observe a 4, so we don't hire. Then we observe a 9, so he hire them and halt the interview process. In this case, we didn't select the optimal candidate, but we were close.

---

But what if we don't know this algorithm and we want to determine which $k$ is best? It isn't immediately intuitive that $k \approx \frac{1}{e}$ is the best number of candidates to skip and so simulating can assist us in finding for which $k$ our probabilility of picking the best candidate is maximized. In the general case, simulations aid in intuition. If we can guess an optimal solution, or perhaps even prove an optimal solution through mathematics, then simulation helps to verify our results.

### How would you simulate?

This is perhaps my favorite part. I will be using R to write this simulation and go through the steps on how to do this simulation.

We will start with a single simulation for arbitrary $k$, where we want to create 1000 candidates each with distinct rankings.

```
x <- sample(1:1000, 1000)
```

Now that we have our sample, we want to find the best candidate among the first $k$ candidates, which can be done with

```
init_best <- max(x[1:k])
```

Next, we begin by looping through the remaining candidates until we find one who is better than the best of our first $k$ candidates. Note that we only simuluate up to $n-1$ candidates for $k$, because it doesn't make sense to skip every candidate as that always results in no hire.

```
for (i in (k+1):999) {
    if (x[i] > init_best) {
        candidate_score <- x[i]
        candidate_num <- i
        break
    }
}
```

So, from here, we have recorded the candidates score. We can quickly verify if this candidate is the best candidate by checking if their ranking is the max ranking. Since we have 1000 candidates, we do this with

```
if (candidate_score == 1000)
    success = success + 1
```

That is, we record that we successfully chose the best candidate and increment some value that keeps track of that. Using these, we can write a few loops to run this simulation several times which is shown below

```
sims <- 10000
p <- c()
p[1] <- 0
cand_ave <- c()
cand_ave[1] <- 0
for (k in 2:999) {
  success <- 0
  for (n in 1:sims) {
    x <- sample(1:1000, 1000)
    init_best <- max(x[1:k])
    candidate_score = -1
    for (i in (k+1):1000) {
      if (x[i] > init_best) {
        candidate_score <- x[i]
        break
      }
    }
    if (candidate_score == 1000)
      success <- success + 1
  }
  p[k] <- success/sims
  cat(k, " complete \n")
}
plot(1:999, p, type = "l", xlab = "Candidates Skipped",
     ylab = "Probability of selecting Best Candidate",
     main = "The Secretary Problem")
```

So, we create a collection of probabilities so that later on, we can plot these values. We also initialize candidate_score at -1 before each loop so as to signify the case where we end up not hiring anyone. After running this simulation 10000 times for each $k$, the results are as follows

[image: Results]

Within this simulation, we find that the $k$ value(s) that maximizes $p$ is
$k = 332$ or $k = 374$ with $p = .3789$.

We know that the asymptotic $k_n^*$ and $p_n^*$ values are $\dfrac{n}{e}$ and $\dfrac{1}{e}$ respectively and these results are fairly close to those values which would be in this case
$$k_{1000} \approx 369 \quad \quad p_{1000} \approx .369$$

So the simulation approximately confirms the asymptotic values.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you be a bit more specific? How would I verify through simulation that $k_n^*$ converges asymptotically to $n/e$ for large $n$? How would simulation help me to do so? Why wouldn't I take the limit with $n\to\infty$, like in the answer above?

Comment: Your simulation, however you should choose to write it, will result in estimates of $k-n^*$ and $p_n^*$. Plot these estimates against $n$ and you should see that although the plot changes radically towards to beginning, it will start to converge towards the asymptotic values for higher $n$.

Comment: But what will my estimates for $k-n^*$ be? Should I just check for random $n$ what the optimal $k$ is? I have a function that plots the optimal value for $n = 5,\ldots,100$ but I don't see where the simulation comes in.

Comment: Well, you could do that, sure. And just see that the function goes converges towards the asymptotic result. But consider for a moment that you’re the manager. Maybe you don’t understand mathematics much and you just don’t trust it. Don’t just use the function, actually simulate the process. Write code to simulate candidates in a line and stop when the professor selects a candidate and record that value as the estimated $p_n$ and $k_n$. You can then even compare that to the optimal results by whatever function you have.

Comment: I see what you mean now, thanks! But which stopping method should I let the professor use then? Because if I let him use the optimal stopping method, the results will be exactly like the function I mentioned earlier right?

Comment: @titusAdam if you give me a bit, I’ll edit this answer to go more in depth into the simulation side of this.

Comment: @titusAdam I've updated the answer quite a bit. Hopefully this helps. If you use R, you can run this simulation as well. I didn't set a seed, so it won't look the exact same, but hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your derivations to deduce the asymptotics of $k_n^*$ for large $n$. However, for smaller $n$, it's not trivial to derive the maximal $r$. You'll end up with a $n$'th degree polynomial in $r$, which is nasty to optimize over integers $r$, and may have surprising behavior for smaller $n$.

Explicitely, for large $n$, and $r=cn$,

$$P(k)\approx \frac{cn-1}{n}(\ln n - \ln (cn))\approx -c\ln(c),$$

so taking derivatives gives $\ln(c)=-1$, or $c=1/e$, which can be verified to give the maximum (e.g. second derivative test). Thus $k^*_n\approx n/e$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! How would simulation solve this problem for small $n$?

Comment: The same way you'd simulate it for any $n$: uniformly at random pick the best candidate, and then run simulations for every possible $k_n^*=1,2,\cdots,n$.